# Choosing optimal alpha in elastic net logistic regression

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet

I'm performing an elastic-net logistic regression on a dataset using the glmnet package in R.
I'm tuning the Alpha by cross-validation. See R code below:

```
for(j in 1:length(a)){ 
  
  for (i in 1:nAlphaIterations){ 
    set.seed(i) 
    cv <- cv.glmnet(X_dataset, Y_dataset, nfold = 10, family = "binomial", type.measure = "deviance", standardize = TRUE, paralle = F, alpha = a[j]) 
    currAlpha <-   data.frame( 
      cvm = cv$cvm[cv$lambda == cv$lambda.1se], 
      lambda.1se = cv$lambda.1se, 
      alpha = a[j], 
      seed = i) 
    
    allAlpha <- rbind(allAlpha, currAlpha) # all current alphas combined
  } 
  print(j) 
}
```

However, I am not sure which type of measure I should use for determing the alpha. Deviance? Or is AUC better?

Comment: problem with this approach is that every CV run will have different data splits. The evaluation will be very noisy. The type of performance measure depends mostly on the task. However I do not think deviance is an option.

Comment: There is also a similar question here: [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/84012/choosing-optimal-alpha-in-elastic-net-logistic-regression)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to achieve high classification accuracy, you can use `type.measure = "class"` inside `cv.glmnet()` function, which optimizes for classification accuracy. To address random data splits in the comment, you can fix your `foldid` by creating a vector of fold index for each observation, as suggested in (https://glmnet.stanford.edu/articles/glmnet.html#introduction-1):

> Users can explicitly control the fold that each observation is assigned to via the foldid argument. This is useful, for example, in using cross-validation to select a value for $\alpha$